# How to create an efficient 3D matrix using the Eigen library in C++?

Tags: c++, eigen, robotics

For a robotics project I need a 3D matrix of a pre-defined size. Using the Eigen library, I don't see how: 
1.) to create a large pre-defined matrix, seems like I have to use matrixXd but that's for a dynamic matrix. 
2.) create a 3D matrix, i. e. size = (int from 200 to 1000) and `matrix (size, size, size)`

Comment: There is an unsupported tensor class, see [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/classEigen_1_1Tensor.html).

Comment: Also, note that a pre-defined sized `Matrix` is allocated on the stack, whereas the dynamic `MatrixXd` is allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

1. Creating a large matrix using static allocation is not advised as it will degrade the performance.
2. Instead of a 3D matrix, you can create a Vector of 2D matrices.

   eg: Eigen::MatrixX< Eigen::MatrixXf, DIMENSION, 1> tmp;

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find a way to build a 3d matrix in my project. 
Use the vector:

```
typedef vector<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>> M3;
```

If you want to initialize a  pre-defined matrix with dimension (k,m,n), just use:

```
M3 W(k, M2(m, n));
```

This way is easy to store Eigen Matrix. But if you want to calculate 3d matrix, you should slice it to many 2d Matrix and use a loop to get the 3d result.